# how do i set two values in php slim

Tags: php, stripe-payments, slim

I am using slim PHP for stripe everything works fine but I am in a situation where I need two values for a single product code.

explanation for codes
USD, cad  'private morning safari' & 'with Atv' are the value generated from HTML through JSON decode and in PHP slim if this value is passed by HTML then it reacts according to it example if in HTML is selected in USD then a card will be used in PHP slim stripe as payment and if EUR than Alipay.

my question is how can i use `or` and `&` In PHP slim  :

- i want `or` in usd or CAD => ['card'],
- i want  `&` in 'private morning safari' & 'with Atv' => 'pr27383002',

```html
$app->post('/checkout_sessions', function(Request $request, Response $response) use ($app)  {
  $params = json_decode($request->getBody());
  $payment_method_types = [
    'usd' => ['card'],
    'eur' => ['alipay'],
    'cad' => ['card']
  ];
  $products = [
    'private morning safari' & 'with Atv' => 'pr27383002',
  ];
```

Comment: What are you going to do with these arrays once you have them? Are you sending them to an API? Are you using them to display information to your user?

Comment: like what more information is needed, you mean the HTML section or javascript of json?

Comment: basically its like from my html file I get this USD as a value and in stripe PHP slim file I write like USD value represents as Card in payment method I use them as prams $payment_method_types so if my HTML is sending EUR alipay is used as payment method

Comment: 'private morning safari' & 'with Atv' => 'pr27383002', i am receiving error from stripe  You must specify either `product` or `product_data` when creating a price.
when i use and if i remove and just use single value it works well

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOLRATK4pVA you can refer here this is what I have been using but I cant set two value with &

Comment: do you need any other info?

Comment: anyone pls help me with this